# Installing ADT error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

```
Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/R-3.7-201106131736/content.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7/R-3.7.1-201109091335/content.jar.
Read timed out
```

When I requested installation, exactly how it is written here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

did you download this file

> dl.google.com/android/ADT-15.0.0.zip

and installed by hand?
(add this file as repo)

did it fail too?

or try without https

> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I tried with http but it still do not work. How to add it as repo? I do not know how to install it by hand

Comment: After I tried http, this is the error which I am getting           An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_15.0.0.v201110251216-213216.jar.
Read timed out

Comment: check this out http://www.limfy.com/2011/08/how-to-fix-android-adt-plugin-installation-error-for-eclipse/

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to install adt on 64 bit version of Eclipse, which is not supported for android development.... so if you do not want to loose your time please do not do that :)